# Appending and Removing Repeated Values on a column of a Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a dataframe that I made via df4.append(df3,ignore_index= True) ; however, I am having some issues removing repeats in my column Gene_symbol while still keeping the values in case 1, 2 and 3. I have already tried df4.drop_duplicates(["Gene_Symbol"]) and various other methods, all of which tend to delete the other rows and with it my Data.

What I am getting is this:

```
         X       Case1       Case2       Case3       Gene_Symbol 
8026    8025    0.5326718   0.0000000   0.0000000   GAPDHS;TMEM147
32531   32530   0.0000000   0.5416982   0.0000000   GAPDHS;TMEM147
57051   57050   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.4821592   GAPDHS;TMEM147
```

What I would like to have is a dataframe below where my actual values are kept

```
     Case1       Case2       Case3       Gene_Symbol 
    0.5326718   0.5416982   0.4821592   GAPDHS;TMEM147
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: So you're looking to replace the _0_ measurements in the _CaseX_ columns with actual measurements? Is the situation given above (there is only 1 valid measurement, and three lines total) applicable to all of your data?

Comment: That is correct! Sorry if the question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
df = df.groupby('Gene_Symbol')['Case1', 'Case2', 'Case3'].sum().reset_index()

    Gene_Symbol     Case1       Case2       Case3
0   GAPDHS;TMEM147  0.532672    0.541698    0.482159
```

Comment: Hi is there anyway to make it so that rather then writing the Case 1 and Case 2 I can have it more in a loop ? I tried doing the following                 df4 = df4.groupby('Gene_Symbol')["Case "+str(index)].sum().reset_index()     but I ended up only being left with case 3. Thanks!

Comment: You can use df.groupby('Gene_Symbol').sum().reset_index() if you are not bothered about column X as this would end up adding values in X as well

Comment: Thank you so much ur a genius !!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, if all *Cases* columns contain only one non zero values for each *gene*, this should work (assume you don't have the `X` column which looks like an index):

```
df.set_index('Gene_Symbol').stack()[lambda x: x != 0].unstack(level=1).reset_index()

#      Gene_Symbol     Case1       Case2       Case3
#0  GAPDHS;TMEM147  0.532672    0.541698    0.482159
```

Or:

```
df
#          X       Case1       Case2       Case3       Gene_Symbol
#8026   8025    0.532672    0.000000    0.000000    GAPDHS;TMEM147
#32531  32530   0.000000    0.541698    0.000000    GAPDHS;TMEM147
#57051  57050   0.000000    0.000000    0.482159    GAPDHS;TMEM147

df.drop('X', 1, inplace=True)

df.set_index('Gene_Symbol').stack()[lambda x: x != 0].unstack(level=1).reset_index()
​
#      Gene_Symbol     Case1       Case2       Case3
#0  GAPDHS;TMEM147  0.532672    0.541698    0.482159
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to remove my values for Case 2 and Case 3. Thank you though

Comment: What do you mean *remove values for Case 2 and Case 3*? if you mean have the *nans*, you can use `fillna(0)`.

Comment: so it removes the X column but I still end up losing my values for Case 2 and 3.

Comment: So I lose my values for case 2  and case 3: .541698 and .482159, which is replaced with 0.

Comment: Not sure. This seems to work on the sample data for me.